# Python Django: Join on the same table

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to use `ltree` extension in PostgreSQL to build a full-text address search engine.

My model looks like this (it's slightly simplified):

```
from django.db import models


class Addresses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So, data in this table will look like this:

```
id  |   name       |  path
----------------------------
 1  |  USA         | 1
 2  |  California  | 1.2
 3  |  Los Angeles | 1.2.3
```

I want to do a full-text search on the aggregated name of each entity.
Basically I need to convert each row in table to the next format to do a search:

```
    id  |           full_name            |  path
-------------------------------------------------
  1     |  USA                           |   1
  2     |  California USA                |   1.2
  3     |  Los Angeles California USA    |   1.2.3
```

I'm doing that in such way, so user can perform queries like 'los ang cali' or similar.
I have no problems to do that with **raw** PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT *, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', full_address), query) AS rank 
FROM (SELECT s.id, s.path, array_to_string(array_agg(a.name ORDER BY a.path DESC), ' ') AS full_address
        FROM "Addresses" AS s INNER JOIN "Addresses" AS a
        ON (a.path @> s.path) GROUP BY s.id, s.path, s.name
) AS subquery, to_tsquery('english', %s) as query WHERE   to_tsvector('english', full_address) @@ query
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

That works fine, but while using **RawQuerySet**, I can't use things like `.filter()`, `.group_by()`, pagination, etc.

The main constraint to reproduce it in Django is this **JOIN**:

```
JOIN "Addresses" AS a ON (a.path @> s.path)
```

it's used to join all ancestors of each element and then aggregate them using `array_agg()`, `array_to_string` functions, so the output of these functions can be used further in **full-text search**.

If anyone have better ideas how to implement such kind of thing using **Django ORM**, please advise.

Comment: I might suggest using django-mptt package for this. It will make your model have tree structure, so you would have USA as parent node and all states as the subtree of it, etc. Using the package you can get children/parents in one query without traveling down/up the tree. I'm not 100% sure it's what you want, but check it out https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Comment: Django does not have a way to join like that if it is not by a known field or using extra/raw stuff.

Comment: I have an idea but I don't know the @> operator. It doesn't exist in my postgresql installation (9.5). Did you perhaps mean >= ? with this operator the table structure you menton above can be created.

Comment: It's actually a specific operator for **ltree** - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ltree.html. And here is some workaround for Django to work with **ltree** - https://github.com/whitglint/ltreefield

Comment: did you have any luck with unmanaged tables as in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

You need an unmanaged model backed by a VIEW.

### An unmanaged model.

Creating an unmanaged model is achieved by setting the [managed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#managed) meta option of a model to false.

> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be
>   performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an
>   existing table or a **database view** that has been created by some other
>   means. This is the only difference when managed=False. All other
>   aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal. This
>   includes

Emphasis mine.

Thus if you create an unmanaged model it can be represented by a view on the database and you have access to `.filter()`, `.group_by()` on it.

### The View.

The view is your query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view full_address_tree AS

SELECT a.*, s.id, s.path, array_to_string(array_agg(a.name ORDER BY a.path DESC), ' ') AS full_address
        FROM "Addresses" AS s INNER JOIN "Addresses" AS a
        ON (a.path @> s.path) GROUP BY s.id, s.path, s.name
```

### Creating the model

```
class FullAddressTree(models.Model):
    # copy paste the fields from your Addresses model here
    sid = models.IntegerField()
    sid = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        # this is the most important part
        managed = False
        db_table = 'full_address_tree' # the name of the view
```

Thus now you have a model which can be used to do full text searches without having to resort to raw queries. Thus you have the full power of the Django ORM at your disposal.

### Migrations.

If you want a migration, you will find that ./manage.py makemigrations results in a dummy migration. ./manage.py sqlmigrate will reveal that no sql queries are executed for this migration.

To fix it and to have the view created automatically add a RunSQL call to the `operations` list in that migration.

```
migrations.RunSQL(''' COPY PASTE SQL QUERY FROM ABOVE ''')
```

### Caveats

The unmanaged model you have created is read only. Attempting to Create, Replace, Update or Delete will fail. If you need this functionality you will need an INSTEAD trigger.

Answer (score 1):

So big +1 @shang-wang for their suggestion on django-mptt. Using that gets around your problem because all the tree operations in MPTT work as a regular `QuerySet` and thus are chainable to `annotate` and `aggregate`. The only thing I'm not sure of is if your problem is insert heavy. If you're just planning on dumping a lot of data into the table once, then no big deal. If you're going to be modifying the tree often then it might be a bit more of a problem. For good description of what MPTT is and how it works http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Anyhow, your original problem of getting all the ancestors of a node then becomes
`la_node.get_ancestors()`. That gets around the join constraint you mentioned which should make it possible to reformulate the remainder of the query.